# Why is the following graph not planar

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Consider the following graph:

[image]

I can't find a planar drawing of this graph. But I want to show it formally. My approach is to use $\textbf{Kuratowski's Thoerem}$, but I can't find a Subgraph that is homeomorphic to $K_{5}$ or $K_{3,3}$. Hope somebody can help me.

Comment: Aren't $\{a, d, f\}$ and $\{b, c, e\}$ the two disjoint sets of $K_{3, 3}$?

Comment: All the vertices have degree 3, so there's no way to fit a $K_5$ in there.  What about a $K_{3,3}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\{a,d,f\}$ and $\{b,c,e\}$ are the different sets of a $K_{3,3}$ copy. All edges are as in this bipartite graph. The whole graph is just isomorphic to it...